# Why can my Github Action step not connect to Docker container?

Tags: docker-compose, cypress, github-actions, jekyll

In Github Actions I want to test my frontend through Cypress. I run my Jekyll application in a Docker container and then run the tests in the next step. However, when connecting the Cypress tests to the Docker container I get a 'Connection refused' error. Does anyone know how I can access my container after running docker-compose?

This is my Github Actions yml file:

```
name: Cypress Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v4.2.0
        with:
          start: docker-compose up -d
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  jekyll:
    image: jekyll/jekyll:latest
    command: jekyll serve --watch --force_polling --verbose
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/jekyll
```

Comment: You might have to run the docker command in a separate step
`- id: run-docker`
   `run: docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 0):

So apparently although my Jekyll container started perfectly fine, the actual Jekyll server crashed on startup. I needed to specify the UID and GID of Github actions to my Jekyll environment in order for it to start correctly.

This is my new docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  jekyll:
    image: jekyll/jekyll:latest
    command: jekyll serve --watch --force_polling --verbose
    hostname: localhost
    environment:
      JEKYLL_UID: 1001
      JEKYLL_GID: 1001
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/jekyll
```